# configure Bigtable and gRPC logging

Tags: java, slf4j, google-cloud-bigtable, grpc-java

I would like to configure logging from Google Cloud Bigtable (gRPC) like the other modules of my application

Logs with SLF4J/log4j with properties configured to dismiss INFO logs from spark

```
2017-01-11 10:44:08 INFO  algoServingLauncherTest$:12 - Starting algo Serving...
2017-01-11 10:44:09 INFO  MongoDBAlgorithm$:12 - Retrieving all algorithms from mongodb://mongo:27017/mycompany/algorithms...
2017-01-11 10:44:09 INFO  MongoDBAlgorithmHandler$:12 - Algorithms retrieval succeeded (1 algorithms)
2017-01-11 10:44:09 INFO  MongoDBPredictor$:12 - Retrieving all predictors from mongodb://mongo:27017/mycompany/predictors...
2017-01-11 10:44:09 INFO  MongoDBPredictorHandler$:12 - Predictors retrieval succeeded (13 predictors)
```

logs from Bigtable gRPC

```
Jan 11, 2017 10:44:23 AM com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl <init>
INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@1cf6d1be] Created with target directaddress:///bigtable.googleapis.com/[omitted]:443
Jan 11, 2017 10:44:23 AM com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl <init>
INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@4b29d1d2] Created with target directaddress:///bigtable.googleapis.com/[omitted]:443
Jan 11, 2017 10:44:23 AM com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl <init>
INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@7f485fda] Created with target directaddress:///bigtable.googleapis.com/[omitted]:443
```

I would like to force logging to use SLF4J/Log4j.

What should I do ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't an existing direct SLF4J integration in grpc; grpc currently uses java.util.logging which has some complications.

You may want to read the [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1577) which discusses this in a lot more detail, and in particular [this comment](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1577#issuecomment-228342706) suggests that you may have some success with [SLF4JBridgeHandler](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possibl to disable INFO logging than ?

Comment: OK disabling with `val log = java.util.logging.Logger.getGlobal` and 
 `log.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF)` works